# How does the Kucherov reaction work if the alkyne is aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I know how the Kucherov reaction works for aliphatic alkynes, but what if the alkyne has a phenyl attached? How will the aromatic ring affect the reaction of alkynes with water?

Comment: Presumably you're most interested in disubstituted alkynes. Is that correct?

Comment: No, monosubstituted alkynes, I'm interested about the case of an symmetrical alkine monosubstituted with an aromatic ring for the begining, then asymmetrical alkine

Comment: A symmetrical alkyne cannot be monosubstituted. It sounds to me like you want to know about this reaction: $$\ce{PhC#CH->[\ce{Hg^2+}][\ce{H2O}]?}$$ or do you want to know about this reaction: $$\ce{PhC#CR->[\ce{Hg^2+}][\ce{H2O}]?}\\ \text{R=alkyl}$$

Comment: I want both reactions